# Cannot find path while trying to read txt to String

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to read a txt file to string inside my groovy script. Therefore I use the following code:

```
stage('exists'){

    def filePath = "C:\\JenkinsSlave\\lastSuccessfull\\folder\\lastSuccess.txt"

    node('fetch'){


        if (fileExists(filePath)) {
            echo 'Yes'
            File file = new File(filePath).text 
            println file 
        } else {
            echo 'No. create file...'
            fileOperations([fileCreateOperation(fileContent: '1.111', fileName: filePath)])

        }

    }
}
```

If the file does not exists the script create it. And if it exists the if cause detects the file. But If I want to read the content I get an `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\JenkinsSlave\lastSuccessfull\folder(The system cannot find the path specified)` error message. But how is this possible? The path can't be false because I use the same variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw that there is a command in Jenkins pipeline syntax

```
fileContents = readFile encoding: 'UTF-8', file: filePath
```

But I am still wondering why jenkins gives me the error above while using simple groovy code...

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
 File file = new File(filePath)).text 
        println file
```

with

```
def file = new File(filePath)).text 
        println file
```